# polymorphic relations setup?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I like to create polymorphic relations and I am not sure if I am doing the right way in my case?

I have `description_groups` table and it is belong to many `descriptions`

In regarding to laravel polymorphic relation, table such as `customers` and `orders` can have many `descriptions`

Here is database schema I have came up with:

`description_groups` table:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Stock Movement |
+----+----------------+
```

`descriptions` table:

`description_groups` is belong to many `descriptions` listed below

```
+----+----------------------+--------+
| id | description_group_id | name   |
+----+----------------------+--------+
|  1 |                    1 | Name 1 |
|  2 |                    1 | Name 2 |
|  3 |                    1 | Name 3 |
|  4 |                    1 | Name 4 |
+----+----------------------+--------+
```

Using  `polymorphic_table` table I can define which table and entry can have description. what the table name should be? For example:

```
+----+----------------+------------+----------+
| id | description_id | table_name | table_id |
+----+----------------+------------+----------+
|  1 |              4 | customers  |        2 |
|  2 |              2 | orders     |       10 |
+----+----------------+------------+----------+
```

`customers table`:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | name            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Customer Name 1 |
|  2 | Customer Name 2 |
|  3 | Customer Name 3 |
+----+-----------------+
```

So this mean `Customer Name 2` have `Name 4` entry description which is belong to `Stock Movement` entry.

Comment: Table name shouldn't be a table, it should be a path to the model representing the table. `App\Customer` and `App\Order` is fine. Also, shouldn't be called `table_name`, but `entity_name` and the `table_id` should also be `entity_id`. Cleaner, more straight forward, follows Laravel's design pragma.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you, feel free to post your answer. `descriptions` and and `description_groups` look fine to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has built in support for polymorphic relationship, which you can find out more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

I do not really understand why you set up your schema the way you did, however this is how I would do it such that customers and orders can have descriptions.

```
descriptions ( <id>, name, content, describable_type, describable_id )
customers (<id>, name)
orders (<id>, items)
```

Note that `descriable_type` is a string, and `descriable_id` is an unsigned integer.

Next you will have to set up the relationship, as described in the docs (note the comments which tell you which model file they belongs to):

```
// In App\Description
public function describable() 
{
   return $this->morphTo();     
}

// In App\Customer
public function descriptions()
{
   return $this->morphMany('App\Description', 'describable');
}

// In App\Orders
public function descriptions()
{
   return $this->morphMany('App\Description', 'describable');
}
```

Now, here's one thing that the Laravel docs don't mention; a one-to-one polymorphic relationship is created the same way as a one-to-one normal relationship, while a one-to-many polymorphic relationship is created the same way as a one-to-many normal relationship...(just think of `morphTo` as a polymorphic `belongsTo`)

So to use this:

```
// be sure to set the correct $guarded access before using create()
$description = Description::create(['name' => 'Name', 'content' =>'Lorem Ispum";
$customer = Customer::create(['name' => 'Customer 1']);
$customer->describable()->associate($description);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Extrakun. That was very helpful. What I don't understand why we need `descriable_id` when we have `description.id`. `descriptions` table  is like predefined list that is link with `description_groups` table. So basically if user select `Stock Movement` from a group and then show a list of descriptions..  User choose any from description list and then save into pivot. Make sense?

Comment: A "describable" does not refer to the description, but rather what the description is describing. So it refers to either a customer or an order in your case.  The describable_id is the id of the customer or order it belongs to, and the describable_type stores whether it's a customer or an order.